# java pointers error "actual and formal arguments lists differ in length"

Tags: java, pointers

hello i have a node class :

```
public class NodoLista{
    private int dato;
    private NodoLista sig;

    //next 
    public void setSig(NodoLista s){
        this.sig=s;
    }
    public NodoLista getSig(){
        return this.sig;
   }
```

*and the line where i call it (erase 1 node)*

```
trabajo.setSig() = trabajo.getSig().getSig();
```

*trabajo is a working pointer so i dont modify the starting one*

i tried

```
NodoLista sig=trabajo.getSig().getSig();
trabajo.setSig()=sig;//but this line still give the same error
```

Comment: You can't put a method call on the left hand side of an assignment statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
trabajo.setSig()=sig; // you cannot assign a value to a method call as well as the method arguments are incorrect
```

to

```
trabajo.setSig(trabajo.getSig().getSig()); // your actual setter 'public void setSig(NodoLista s)'
```

Comment: ty , such a dumb question